# Systemcrash with mysql-object query in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I tried to write my code as short as possible but I discovered something strange here.

If I fetch the query within a 'while loop' the system crashes.

Here's an example.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
while ($row = $db_ob->query($sql)->fetch_array()){
echo $row['one'];
}
```

Is this due to my machine or what can I do?

If I write it like my second example, there are no problems

```
$data =  $db_ob->query($sql)->fetch_array()['one'];
```

Comment: "System crashes" as in "whole computer goes down and needs reboot"? You should reinstall PHP then.

Comment: it is only a 500 error, but the system does not stop the loop

Comment: Yeah, because you're firing a new query every time.

Comment: You are looping your query. It will go on without end, resulting in a server error (probably max execution time..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you re-run the query on every loop iteration, so it will never end. You need to be sure to only run the query once, then iterate over the results.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = $db_ob->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row['one'];
}
```

Comment: I might have known it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script execute mysql Query, Retriving datas 'N' times, So you need to rewrite as like,

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$Result = $db_ob->query($sql);
while ($row = $Result->fetch_array()){
    echo $row['one'];
}
```